# Как исправить мою задачу, помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: c

В каждом интервале строгого возрастания в массиве заменить все значения в данном интервале на среднее значение в интервале. У меня заменяет неправильно или заменяет не все, или заменяет не все интервалы строго возрастания.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

void random(int n, int *a)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,count=0,s=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int* a;
    a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    random(n, a);
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[i+1] && !count)
        {
            for (j = i; j < n; j++)
            {
                count++;
                s = s + a[j];
                a[i] = s / count;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("      %d", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Помогите найти ошибку, или объясните как правильно изменить код, чтобы все было хорошо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Помогите найти ошибку

Сходу видно три ошибки:

1. Накопительную переменную *s* Вы обнуляете только один раз - при объявлении. А надо - каждый раз, перед обработкой очередного интервала.
2. Невозможно в одном цикле и рассчитывать среднее и присваивать значение среднего элементам массива. Надо два цикла: сначала рассчитать среднее, а уже потом - использовать полученное значение.
3. Ну и самая главная ошибка. В задании речь идёт об **интервале**. Для того, что бы работать с интервалом, нужно знать два индекса: индекс начала интервала и индекс его конца. Когда у нас есть эти два значения, рассчитываем среднее, а потом - заменяем.

Поэтому проверки *a[i] < a[i+1]* совершенно недостаточно. Для того, что бы выделить **интервал** нужно:

1. Искать индекс, для которого выполняется условие *a[i] < a[i+1]*
2. Запомнить это значение, как индекс начала интервала
3. Искать индекс, для которого **не** выполняется условие *a[i] < a[i+1]*
4. Запомнить это значение, как индекс конца интервала
5. Рассчитать среднее на этом интервале
6. Заменить значения в интервале на среднее